# Unable to create a file or directory using gitbash

Tags: git-bash

In git bash command prompt I should be at `(MINGW64 ~)` path.

But when I am opening my git bash command prompt, it is showing a default path which is `(MINGW64 /c/users/myfile)`.
Even I used `cd` to come out of `c` directory, but I am finally landing on `(MINW64 /)`.

I should be at `(MINGW64 ~)`. By this only I am getting the error can not create a file or directory.

Answer (score 0):

Check first the value (in your bash session) of HOME

```
echo $HOME
```

If it is / or if it is *not* set, that would explain why `cd` redirects you to path.
Make sure also the CMD wrapper (in which the bash session runs) is not launch as "Administrator", but as your regular user account.